# Inserting a c# string in a webbrowser component, how can i do this?

Tags: c#, html

I'm creating a program that will generate a HTML page with information pulled from a database, some HTML is loaded into a webbrowser component and this webbrowser gets printed.

So in c#:
- There's a webbrowser component
- With some HTML code added into it

I'm trying to insert c# strings, textpulled from a database on specific places in the HTML that gets displayed in the browser component, but i have no clue how. I know in PHP for example, i am able to do  between HTML text for example. Does something similar exist for C#? I'm working in winforms.

I'm looking for something like:

```
<html>
...
...
<h1>$String1</h1>
...
...
</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific and clear!

Comment: If you want to use HTML and Winforms your component to search for is System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: Maybe i should explain again. I have a webbrowser component with HTML inside of it. Lets say i have a c# string that reads: "John Doe" lets say its called string 1. How can i put the value of string 1 between the HTML in the webbrowser component?  So like <h1>*String1*</h1>

Comment: @CryingFreeman has offered a potentially helpful suggestion.  If it turns out to be helpful to you, please say so.  And if it's not what you're looking for, please say why not, that will help clarify your question.